# Turn browser_action button into shortcut link instead of popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How do you make the brower_action button into a direck link (you click on it and it takes you to the page) instead of the little popup?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you describe, the following requirements must be met:

1. Declare a browser-action in your manifest.
2. Do not attach a popup to the browser-action (i.e. do not include a `default_popup` property).
3. From your background-page listen for and handle `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` events (e.g. opening a new tab with a web-page or update the currently active tab).

E.g.:

**In *manifest.json*:**

```
...
"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test Extention"
    "default_icon": {
        "19": "icon19.png",
        "38": "icon38.png"
    },
},
...
```

**In *background.js*:**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab0 {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: "http://www.google.com/" });
});
```